# How can i complete the square when the equation is not in standard form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:

> Use completion of the square to help sketch the graph of the quadratic function
>
> 1) 2+2x-x$^2$

Im not familiar with the equation not being in standard form, i tried putting it into one, but i keep getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we can do is factor out a $-1$ from the expression. This gets us the following expression:
\begin{align} -(x^2 - 2x - 2). \end{align}
Notice that if we multiply out the $-1$ we get the original expression back.

The reason for doing this is that we now have a standard form, just multiplied by some number. So now we can just complete the square for the quadratic in the parentheses. We know that 
\begin{align} x^2-2x+1 \end{align}
is a perfect square (namely $(x-1)^2$). To get that in our expression we just do the regular procedure inside the parentheses, adding and subtracting $1$ *within the parentheses*:
\begin{align} &-(x^2 - 2x +\mathbf{ 1 - 1} - 2)\\
=& -\big((x-1)^2 - 1 - 2\big) \\
=& -\big((x-1)^2 - 3\big). \end{align}
Now we can just multiply out the negative, to get
\begin{align} -(x-1)^2 + 3. \end{align}
To graph the function you just use the same techniques you would were the expression already in standard form, except noting that the negative in front of the $-(x-1)^2$ makes the graph form a downward dome-like shape, rather than a bowl.

Answer (score 3):

For a general quadratic, $ y = ax^2 + bx + c $ (so $a \neq 0$, otherwise it would not be a quadratic) you can always complete the square
$$
y = a\Big(x+\frac{b}{2a} \Big)^2 -\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a} .
$$
Choose $a,b$ and $c$ and apply to your example.